# Sonar multi module consolidated report for afferent and efferent coupling

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a multi module maven project and need to generate a report for afferent (ca) and efferent (ce) couplings across the modules.

Currently when I run mvn sonar:sonar for a multi module project, the ca and ce are reported at module level. This only gives me a idea of how other classes from the same module are referring to a particular class.

I was interested in knowing the ca and ce across multiple modules.

Is that possible with sonar, using a multi module configuration.

Currently to overcome this limitation, I am having to copy sources and classes from all the modules to a single folder and run the sonar report on that.

What is the correct approach. Is there any configuration in sonar that can help?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet available in SonarQube but this is something that we have in the pipe, see http://www.sonarqube.org/what-is-coming-up-for-sonar-in-2013/, first section 'Cartography'.